# how to give the user the option either to pay in dollars Euro or pound?

Tags: magento

I want that user can pay in either of these currencies. But I'm not getting it because in the backend under currency there is an option to select only one currency.

So do we have to write code ourselves, or is there some standard Magento functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following link.

[Adding the Currency Selector to the Magento Onepage Checkout Under https](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/adding-the-currency-selector-to-the-magento-onepage-checkout-under-https/)